# Issue with ListView class in HoloEverywhere library

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to use **HoloEverywhere** library for the project but after building it gives `error` in `ListView` class under widget folder. The error is in `dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)` method. Certain variables are not defined, it seems, such as mListPadding, mIsCacheColorOpaque.

Have I missed anything ?

Comment: please put your code.how can we tell us without reviewing your code.??

Comment: I have just downloaded the code from here and using the code available in library folder https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere. It just gives build error in ListView class.